# android:state_selected="true" doesn't work about ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView which I want its item's background turn into green when the item is pressed and keep in grey when I release my finger.
I use a selector(**listview_item_indicator.xml**) to achieve this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_selected="true" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
</selector>
```

Then I update the xml file of the ListView item to apply this selecor like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/listview_item_indicator"
```

The result is it turn into green when I press the item,but it doesn't keep in grey when I release my finger(it turn to what it was before I pressed it).I think it means `<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"></item>` worked,but `<item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_selected="true" ></item>` didn't work.Why?

Comment: May be doing setSelected(true) for clicked item help.

Comment: set default drawable color in selector

Answer (score 1):

`state_selected` is for selection via trackball or d-pad

I think you are referring to the API 11 `state_activated`

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

EDIT:
You also need to:

1) Set list view to single choice:

```
<ListView
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

2) Highlight item using `listView.setItemChecked(index, true);`

Comment: state_selected represents when a view (or one of its parents) is currently selected.state_actived represents when a view or its parent has been "activated" meaning the user has currently marked it as being of interest. It also doesn't work when I change to state_activated

Comment: Well, that's not all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `android:listSelector` instead of `android:background`

Answer (score 0):

Define default state.

Try this selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_selected="true" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" ></item>
</selector>
```